Customize the "ghost" element with VueDraggable
I use the following library: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable
I have 2 lists where I can dragg one element to the other list. But When i dragg the item its a clone of the icon.
What I am trying to do is while you move the item between the list. Instead of the Icon I want a customize element to be shown as "Ghost elememt".
Within sortableJS you something called "ghostClass" which works but it only adds the custom class.
But now I want also to customize the ghost Element.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Hm, even if I see what you mean it's hard to give an answer straight from this context. Could you please take some time to provide us with a [repro]? Might make things go quite faster overall. I think that using @mousedown on the moving element and binding the given class to it is the way to go. But there might be a lot of ways of achieving such a result.

I found the part where I can customize the "ghost" element within VueDraggable. For future developers with the same question.
You have the following method:
// Called when dragging element changes position
onChange: function(/**Event*/evt) {
    evt.newIndex // most likely why this event is used is to get the dragging element's current index
    // same properties as onEnd
}

So the following resolved my issue:
<VueDraggable :onChange="sectionChange " ...

The function it self:
const sectionChange = (evt) => {
  evt.item.innerHTML = `<div style="margin:0 auto;background:red;width:100px;">ADD ICON</div>`
}


Feel free to accept your own answer when you can.
